# Uncaught Typeerror: cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, properties, innerhtml, typeerror

Can anyone explain what is this error?

> Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

This is the line which is causing the issue:

```
var idPost=document.getElementById("status").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 41):

```
var idPost=document.getElementById("status").innerHTML;
```

The 'status' element does not exist in your webpage.

So document.getElementById("status") return null. While you can not use innerHTML property of NULL.

You should add a condition like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("status") != null){
    var idPost=document.getElementById("status").innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: this worked out like a charm for me in this instance https://jsfiddle.net/gqrhcu6f/

Answer (score 33):

### Update:

The question doesn't ask for jquery. So lets do it without jquery:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    //Do work
});
```

Note this method will not work on IE8.

### Old Answer:

You are calling this script before DOM is ready. If you write this code into jquery's $(function() method it will work.

Comment: This was the culprit in my case. This point should definitely be included in a top answer.

Comment: Yes, this is the simple answer, should've been put to the top.

Comment: @MattSom No it shouldn't, because of the fact that the question never included anything about jQuery and jQuery is not needed for this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

If the script is in the head of your HTML document, the body of your HTML document has not yet been created by the browser, regardless of what will eventually be there (the same result occurs if your script is in the HTML file but above the element). When your variable tries to find document.getElementById("status") it does not yet exist, and so it returns a value of null. When you then use the variable later in your code, the initial value (null) is used and not the current one, because nothing has updated the variable.

I didn't want to move my script link out of the HTML head, so instead I did this in my JS file:

```
var idPost //define a global variable
function updateVariables(){
    idPost = document.getElementById("status").innerHTML; //update the global variable
}
```

And this in the HTML file:

```
<body onload="updateVariables()">
```

If you already have an onload function in place, you can just add the additional line to it or call the function.

If you don't want the variable to be global, define it locally in the function that you are trying to run and make sure the function is not called before the page has fully loaded.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, but I had the existing id, and as egiray said, I was calling DOM before it loaded and Javascript console was showing the same error, so I tried:

```
window.onload = (function(){myfuncname()});
```

and it starts working.

Answer (score 5):

run the code after your html structure in the body statement

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>asdasd</p>
    <p>asdasd</p>
    <p>asdasd</p>
    <script src="myfile.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

While you should ideally highlight the code which is causing an error and post that within your question, the error is because you are trying to get the inner HTML of the 'status' element:

```
var idPost=document.getElementById("status").innerHTML;
```

However the 'status' element **does not exist** within your HTML - either add the necessary element or change the ID you are trying to locate to point to a valid element.

Answer (score 1):

Are you declaring the `<script>` tag before the `#status` element?

If you do, the statement in that  tag will be executed first, and now there is no element with the id `status`.

The best way is to put this script tag right **before** the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Run with this HTML structure
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>OOJS</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="status">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scriptfile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the script executes before the DOM loads.
Try loading the script asynchronously.

```
 <script src="yourcode.js" async></script>
```

Comment: Why would adding the async tag help? As described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp) using this tag will make the script execute as soon as possible (possibly before the DOM is available).

Comment: If the "async" attribute is present, the script and the DOM will run at the same time. If you want to delay the execution of the script until after the DOM is ready you can use the "defer" attribute. Otherwise the script will try to run on elements that don't yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on a file I used while doing a case study on GitHub. I noticed that this error occurs because external JavaScript file declarations are defined in the `<head></head>` field in the HTML file. A situation that could cause this issue is resolved when external JavaScript files are declared at the end of the `<body></body>` field in the HTML file.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("container").innerHTML);
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].innerHTML);
console.log( $(".content")[0].innerHTML );
console.log( $(".content").html() );
console.log( $("#container")[0].innerHTML );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  <title>jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h3>jQuery Library</h3>
    <p class="content">jQuery is a JS library.</p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id `"status"` is not found in the html file it shows the error.

Add the `"status"` id in your html file. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="status">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scriptfile.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake I've done and I hope anyone else doing this will learn from me. I got the same error :

```
app.js:116 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: holder is not defined
    at getRandomMovieById (app.js:116:3)
```

The mistake I did was to use one Javascript file for two HTML files. I created individual files for each of my HTML and it worked awesomely.