# Cannot read property innerHTML of null when i have declared an id

Tags: javascript, html

I want to start of by saying i have read this thread
[Uncaught Typeerror: cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003270/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-innerhtml-of-null)
but it has not helped me at all, and I'm really scratching my head.

I saved my data in localstorage, where I want to get the item, and if it's not there, I append a 'No movie' string instead to my html file.

This is my HTML file:

```
  <div class="container-fluid" id="userinfo">
  <p><strong>Användare</strong></p>
  <p> Philip </p>
  <p><strong>Favoritfilm</strong></p>
  <p id="getFavMovie">  </p>
  </div>
```

This is my JS file:

```
var mymovie = localStorage.getItem("favmovie");
if(mymovie == null){
  document.getElementById("getFavMovie").innerHTML == 'No movie'
}
else{
  document.getElementById("getFavMovie").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("favmovie");
}
```

As you can see, I have declared the id `getFavMovie` so I don't understand the issue of this at all.
Would appreciate some help here.

Comment: you have a typo on the first condition `.innerHTML ==  'no movie'`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am very tired... I thought it said "read" but it said "set" property.
So it was because i didnt use an onload function of javascript in the start:

Thanks for the help anyways guys, my bad!